# How to become admin for Gitlab.com project?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to get to the admin area so I can set the time-to-live for the gitlab container registry token. However, I don't see where that's available to me. I am the sole owner and creator of the project after I signed up for a Gitlab account and clicked to create a new project. My problem is similar to this person:

https://forum.gitlab.com/t/where-is-the-admin-area/5936

except I'm not using Gitlab CE.

So how can I become an admin for my own project so I can change some admin settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have access to the admin area of `gitlab.com`. It is a private instance of Gitlab Enterprise Edition, belonging to Gitlab. They do allow anyone to have unlimited access (any number of public or private repositories as well as groups etc) but you can't be an admin.

Being an admin would mean you could see anyone's projects or delete them etc. That's not reasonable...